# Disable default SMS app on OnePlus

Tags: sms, default-applications, oneplus, debloat

I'm trying to debranch my phone from OnePlus and Google as much as possible. In the last few days, I removed some packages and replaced them with FOSS & trusted companies' apps.

I'm stuck though... I cannot find the default SMS packages and I don't know how to fix or make the new apps default apps. I mean, lock them in the system as the OEM/provider does.

All I can find now from OnePlus are:

```
~: adb shell pm list packages | grep sms
package:com.simplemobiletools.smsmessenger
package:con.android.smspush
~: adb shell pm list packages | grep oneplus
package:com.oneplus.calculator
package:com.oneplus.opscout
package:com.oneplus.opshelf
package:com.oneplus.account
package:com.oneplus.wallpaper
package:com.oneplus.wallpaperresources
package:com.oneplus.brickmode
package:com.oneplus.deskclock
package:com.oneplus.setupwizard
package:com.oneplus.camera.service
package:com.oneplus.push
package:com.oneplus.faceunlock
package:com.oplus.framework.rro.oneplus
package:com.oneplus.canvasresources
package:com.oneplus.opwlb
package:android.autoinstalls.config.oneplus
package:net.oneplus.launcher
```

<sup>[Screenshot of terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkfG0.png)</sup>

Comment: have you considered to simply install LineageOS (if your device model is supported): https://download.lineageos.org/devices Manually removing packages is very time consuming and has the risk of making your phone non-bootable so that you have to perform a factory reset and start over again.

Comment: OnePlus has its [own messaging app](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/oneplus-ltd/oneplus-messages-2/oneplus-messages-2-6-0-0-6-210806145124-955b106-release/oneplus-messages-6-0-0-6-210806145124-955b106-android-apk-download/) with package name `com.oneplus.mms`. However, looking at [a YouTube tutorial video for newer phones (e.g. OnePlus Nord CE 2 Lite)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7f3HZSkWV9g) looks like it's using [Google Messages](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.messaging) which is `com.google.android.apps.messaging`.